# How to pre-select some values in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select in a project. When a user clicks to update a post, I fetch the post's original data and fill the form. However I am not able to pre-fill the Select component.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      tags : [], // this contains the list of all the tags in system
      incomingTags : [] // will contain the tags which are linked with the post
      selectedTags : [] // contains the tags that have been selected by user
  }
}

selectRef = null;

componentDidMount() {
  fetch all the tags
  this.setState({tags : fetchedTags});
  fetch the post data
  this.setState({incomingTags : fetchedPostTags});
}

handleTagInputChange = (selectedOptions) => {
  this.setState({ selectedTags : selectedOptions });
}

render() {
  return (
       <CreatableSelect
           ref={ref => {this.selectRef = ref;}} 
           isMulti 
           options={this.state.tags}
           onChange={this.handleTagInputChange}
       />
  )
}

}
```

Things I have tried -

1. Using `defaultValue={this.state.defaultTags}` but it does not change when the state is set.
2. Using `value={this.state.defaultTags}` but then I am not able to remove the selected tags or select any other tags. I went through a similar query - [react-select: pre-select a value in multi-select dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52955622/react-select-pre-select-a-value-in-multi-select-dropdown)
3. Using `this.selectRef.selectOption()` but it does not work for selecting multiple items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use controlled component, you have to set both `value` and `onChange`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';

export default class CreatableSingle extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tags : [],
    }
  }

  handleChange = (
    newValue
  ) => {
    this.setState({ tags: newValue })
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        value={this.state.tags}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had missed out to include my onChange function originally. I have added that in the code now. I have an array which will contain all the tags that the user selects and in the handler i set that array

Comment: Now you are modifying `selectedTags`, but your `tags` is still the same, that's why you can't select anything. You have to use the same array

Comment: Thanks @konrad realised what I was missing.